# jQuery activate .click() only when clicking specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to create a cookie notification that will use .slideToggle (or slideUp/Down) to hide the element once a user has clicked "agree" (or cancel, once I add it).

Currently, the element will slideToggle when you click anywhere on the page, not just when clicking the "agree" button like I am trying to do.

I am doing this on a Wordpress.org site (I am unsure if that can affect it), and I am only just learning JavaScript/jQuery so I apologize if i am misunderstanding how .click or .slideToggle works.

The code is as follows:

```
<style>
.test{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var agree=function(){getElementById("#agree")};
    $(agree).click(function(){
        $("#box").slideToggle();
    });
</script>

<div class="test" id="box">
    <p>We Use Cookies</p>
    <button id="agree" type="button">Agree</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you attempt to wire up your event before the element exists:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#agree").click(function(){
        $("#box").slideToggle();
    });
</script>

<div class="test" id="box">
    <p>We Use Cookies</p>
    <button id="agree" type="button">Agree</button>
</div>
```

You can't add an event to an element that doesn't exist yet.

You can fix this a number of ways:

1 Add code after the element exists:

```
<div class="test" id="box">
    <p>We Use Cookies</p>
    <button id="agree" type="button">Agree</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#agree").click(function(){
        $("#box").slideToggle();
    });
</script>
```

2 Use document ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { 
        $("#agree").click(function(){
            $("#box").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="test" id="box">
    <p>We Use Cookies</p>
    <button id="agree" type="button">Agree</button>
</div>
```

3 Use event delegation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", "#agree", function(){
        $("#box").slideToggle();
    });
</script>

<div class="test" id="box">
    <p>We Use Cookies</p>
    <button id="agree" type="button">Agree</button>
</div>
```

---

> the element will slideToggle when you click anywhere on the page

what's happening is that after `var agree=function(){getElementById("#agree")};` then `agree == null` so you're doing `$(null).click(...` which then applies to the whole page.   If you changed this to `$("#agree").click(...` then you'd have the issue described above (which is why you couldn't get it to work this way)

Comment: This solved it, thank you. I was unaware that it mattered where the JavaScript code was in relation to the HTML it was trying to interact with. I think I had everything inside (document).ready{} previously and at some point along the way I removed it and didn't realize that was what broke it.

Answer (score 1):

This `agree` function never returns anything. `var agree=function(){getElementById("#agree")};` Additionally, you never call the function (only pass a reference to the function). Lastly, you should put your jquery inside the [document ready event](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) so your entire page has loaded before the script runs.

Try this javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#agree").click(function(){
        $("#box").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: That is how I originally did it since it seemed to be the most correct, however it does not seem to work. The element no longer slides, regardless of whether I click on the button or anywhere else. Could this be wordpress messing it up, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: @Casey See my update, you also need your code to run inside the [document ready event](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).